# Speed up web page by compressing large images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a blog slideshow on my web page which accesses images from a given url.

The problem is, people add images with massive resolution (3000px*6000px), which noticeably slows down the animation of the slideshow.

These high resolution images are necessary, but not for this particular purpose, since the images live inside a div of size (300*600)

Is there any way CSS (or some other way) can convert the image to a smaller specified resolution (say 300px * 600px), before scaling down.

This way the animation won't involve high res image frames and so it won't be as laggy.

The only alternative I can think of, is that everytime an image is uploaded on the database, the backend creates a secondary compressed image for this purpose.

However, this seems like a lot of effort.

Comment: CSS only scales client-side in the browser so will not speed up image downloading. Your alternative is the usual way of catering for large images. Typically you would store  a thumbnail size, a standard viewing size (and the original unaltered image if needed for archiving purposes).

Comment: There is no way to solve this on browser-side. You need create two versions of image on your server, with large and small resolution

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, it is not image downloading that is the problem. Once the image has downloaded, the animation begins. But the high-res images cause laggy animation on slow client computers. Yet the high-res isn't necessary due to div size. So is it possible for CSS to download the image at full-res, then scale it down, then add it to the web page for viewing/animating?

Comment: Nope, you'll need to store them on the server and generate smaller versions to show. You could visually scale it down using CSS, but you will still be working with the original image in it's original size. But since you're already letting your users upload the pictures, why not scale them at the same time?

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the reply. I'm not storing the images on my own server, I'm asking users to use an external image hosting service like imgur.com, and they just provide the link. I wanted to avoid asking them to upload 2 images. If there's an alternative image hosting service which creates multiple image copies of different sizes that would be great!

Comment: Normally external image uploading sites allow you to specify the resolution of the image through the URL. Have you tried modifying the URL to specify a 300x600 pixel image?

Comment: How about using `<img src="myimage.jpg" height="300" width="600" />`? Is this a solution?

Comment: @GregPeckory That won't change the native resolution of the image, only the resolution it's drawn at (and from your previous comment it looks like the native res will likely be a bigger factor than output res in page performance). If you need to change the native resolution client-side, the only way I am aware to do that is to redraw the image scaled down onto a small canvas element. That way the original image is gone from memory and the browser doesn't need to constantly scale and draw it, only the small version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said in the comments that bandwidth and download time are not the issue and it's acceptable to download the full res image, scale it down, then add it to the page, please consider the following solution which does exactly that.

Download the original image via AJAX, then use `ctx.drawImage` to draw the image to an HTML canvas with much smaller size. For instance, you can take a 3000px*6000px image and draw it scaled onto a 300px*600px canvas. Then free the original image using JavaScript so that it no longer takes up memory in the browser.

After that, you can use the canvas to do your animations and there should not be nearly as much lag as using the large, original image (since the compositor will need to move much fewer pixels).

**Edit:** According to your later comment, your users are uploading to an external image hosting service, so this solution will prevent them from having to upload a thumbnail version in addition to their full-res version.

---

**If you choose Imgur.com** like you are considering in the comments: They let you modify the image size a bit in the URL. So for instance if you have an image at `https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Os.jpg`, you can use `https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Oss.jpg` for the small version, `https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Osm.jpg` for the medium version, and `https://i.imgur.com/9ZC02Osl.jpg` for the large scaled version (note the s, m, and l at the end of the URLs). That way you can probably avoid drawing to a canvas completely.

Answer (score 1):

This was a site I found a few years agowhich may be of interest: http://sneak.co.nz/projects/img-resizing/

You could store a small version on your site for use in the slideshow. A good way to do this may be to check if a small image is available and if not create it the first time it is called and save it somewhere.

This code will resize an image on the fly but I think you would still have some lag while the image is resized.

```
$photo="sunflower.jpg"; 

$cmd = "convert $photo -thumbnail 200x200 ". 
" -quality 100 JPG:-"; 

header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
passthru($cmd, $retval);
```